# Spring Security redirects to login form instead of returning status 401

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I need Spring to return unauthorized (status 401) instead of redirecting user to login page. Reason is that I'm doing a SPA application backend that already has built in mechanism for redirecting when http status code 401 recieved. Version of Spring Boot I'm working with is 1.3.0 but I've also tried it with 1.4.1 and still getting the same problem.

My security configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/loginPath").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPath")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().deleteCookies("SESSION").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable();
    }
...
}
```

Thanks for helping.

EDIT

There was a view controller mapping for "/error" to redirect user to login page with highest priority assigned. **When that was removed, everything worked as expected.** 
It seems like Spring Security would return 401 and /error as a view but due to redirect config and higher priority it would get overriden.

Comment: I'm receiving an HTTP 401 in an empty Spring Boot (1.4.1.RELEASE) with exact the same configuration. Please post you full configuration.

Comment: That's whole configuration except success handler implementation...I doubt it has anything to do with issue

Comment: Strange. Could you publish somewhere (maybe Github) a sample application that demonstrates you issue, please? I don't see any err.

Comment: See @Arpad example of extending `AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426947/4505142